# rails 3 jQuery UI Datepicker want to enable only specific dates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Registration model and form which uses a datepicker. I want the user to be only able to select dates which correspond to events (another model).

My problem is I can't find the right way to pass the event array to javascript.

this is in the controller:

```
@available_dates = Event.pluck(:start_time).as_json
```

this is in the view:

```
    <script>
       var availableDates = [<%= @available_dates.to_s.html_safe %>] ;
    </script>
```

and this is the js:

```
function available(date) {
    ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    console.log(ymd+' : '+($.inArray(ymd, availableDates)));
    if ($.inArray(ymd, availableDates) != -1) {
        return [true, "","Available"];
    } else {
        return [false,"","unAvailable"];
    }
}
$("#registration_date").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
```

I think I'm doing something wrong in the view since the js array seems to be empty looking at the console...

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This may be moot but have you checked the value of `@available_dates` within the controller?

Comment: `@available_dates` returns `=> ["2013-01-05", "2013-02-02", "2013-03-02"]`  (which are the right dates) and `@available_dates.to_s` returns  `=> "[\"2013-01-05\", \"2013-02-02\", \"2013-03-02\"]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question comments you have mentioned `@available_dates.to_s` returns `"[\"2013-01-05\", \"2013-02-02\", \"2013-03-02\"]"`. This itself will render the array on the page so no need to "box it up" again.

Try changing the following line:

```
var availableDates = [<%= @available_dates.to_s.html_safe %>] ;
```

to this:

```
var availableDates = <%= @available_dates.to_s.html_safe %>;
```

Hope it helps.

If it doesn't you are either clearing the value of `@available_dates` somewhere further in your code or `@available_dates` is not available in the context of your view. Have your tried stepping through the code using `debugger;`?

Comment: i guess that's why my array was empty, removing the brackets gave me the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` can i not use <%= %> in script tags in html.erb or something?

Comment: @defuzed You are either clearing the value of `@available_dates` somewhere further in your code or `@available_dates` is _not_ available in the context of your view. Have your tried stepping through the code using `debugger;`?

Comment: thank you so much for putting me on the right track, i was clearing @available_dates further in my code ... much appreciated!